# Simple progressbar in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.progress = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
           var defaults = { 
             amount: 100,
             color: 'rgb(0,128,0)'
            }; 

        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        //firstly, make me a progressbar
        this.css({'width':'500px','height':'25px','border':'1px solid black','background-color':'white'}); 

        //find the div to extend
        var div = this.find("div");
        div.css({'backgroundColor':options.color,'width':'0'}).animate({'width':options.amount});

        return this;

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

This is the code I have for a jQuery progressbar, called as $(selector).progress(options)
I want to be able to type $(selector).progress(10) in order for the progressbar to slide 10% however it does not work in Google Chrome. Please can someone help me

Comment: The argument to the widget is supposed to be an object containing options, not a number.

Comment: *"I want to be able to type $(selector).progress(10)"* Then you have to modify the code so that the function also accepts a number. Are you having any specific problems with that?

Comment: To extend on what @Barmar said: `$(selector).progress({amount: 10});` ...

Comment: @War10ck i want to shorten that to $(selector).progress(10);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z3Qep/

Answer (score 2):

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.progress = function( options ) {

        // Allow shorthand .progress(amount) or .progress('rgb(...)')
        switch (typeof options) {
        case "number":
            options = { amount: options };
            break;
        case "string":
            options = { color: options };
            break;
        }    

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
           var defaults = { 
             amount: 100,
             color: 'rgb(0,128,0)'
            }; 

        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        //firstly, make me a progressbar
        this.css({'width':'500px','height':'25px','border':'1px solid black','background-color':'white'}); 

        //find the div to extend
        var div = this.find("div");
        div.css({'backgroundColor':options.color,'width':'0'}).animate({'width':options.amount});

        return this;

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsfzx/) showcasing a working example as some this code alone does not show the progressbar.

Comment: I didn't look at the rest of the code of his progressbar, as the question was just about how to supply the argument in an abbreviated fashion. If you want to post an answer that fixes his other bugs, you should do so -- I don't see how these are appropriate comments on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(selector).progress({amount : 10 });
```